# button does not show up correctly when testing responsiveness on chrome

Tags: html, css

Button shows up looking squashed when testing responsiveness in chrome (ipad pro mode).  All the rest on the tablets and mobiles views the button shows correctly.  I tried putting a min-width on the button but this doesn't help as the button looks to big for the page.  Is there any way I can move the button more to the left or set it in the middle.

```
button id="updatePasswordButton" class="btn btn-block btn-success" data-bind="enable: canUpdatePassword, click: resetPassword">



.btn-success {
    min-width: 140px;
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you attach a screenshot of how does it look

Comment: support your query with some code snippet

Comment: There is code there in my question and I have tried uploading a screenshot but apparently I am not able to do that as I require ore points :/

Comment: You're missing the opening < and the closing </button> do you also want the button to not be labeled?

Comment: HI Stefan I have added < these but for some reason I can't show my code in the question if I add them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot to write something between button tag or closing it.
Try this:

```css
.btn-success {
  min-width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<button id="updatePasswordButton" class="btn btn-block btn-success" data-bind="enable: canUpdatePassword, click: resetPassword">Update</button>
```

Comment: and when you want to put some code or script in question, press "CTRL + M",then you brackets won't vanish. Even right now, edit the code, then press the above buttons and put the script in that